# Object of type CustomUser is not JSON serializable" When Updating Django Model Using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Question:**
What could be causing this serialization issue during the update operation, and how can I resolve it? I suspect it's related to how the `CustomUser` object is handled during serialization

I'm working on a Django project using Django Rest Framework, and I've encountered a JSON serialization error when updating a model instance. The project includes a `Gift` model which references a `CustomUser` model. The creation of a `Gift` instance works fine, but updating a `Gift` instance with a new `receiver` (which is a `CustomUser` instance) throws a serialization error.

**Models:**

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models
from .validators import validate_positive
from .custom_user_model import CustomUser

class Gift(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10,
                                blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_positive])
    starred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gifts_given')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gifts_received', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id or not uuid.UUID(str(self.id)):
            self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        super(Gift, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.price:
            return self.name + ' $' + str(self.price)
        else:
            return self.name
```

**Serializer:**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Gift, CustomUser

class GiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    receiver = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())
    links = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='url', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'name', 
            'price', 
            'starred', 
            'user',
            'receiver', 
            'links', 
            'created_at', 
            'updated_at'
            )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'name': {'required': True},
            'user': {'read_only': True},
            'created_at': {'read_only': True},
            'updated_at': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

**Views:**

```py
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .models import Gift
from .serializers import GiftSerializer

class GiftList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = GiftSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gift.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.validated_data['user'] = request.user
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

class GiftDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = GiftSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gift.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Error:**
When I attempt to update a `Gift` instance using the `PUT` method, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type CustomUser is not JSON serializable
```

This error occurs only during an update operation, specifically in the `GiftDetails` view.

**Tests:**
I've written tests for both creating and updating `Gift` instances. The create test passes, but the update test fails with the aforementioned error.

```py
# Test cases for Gift creation and updating (omitted for brevity)
```

Comment: Probably you should show `CustomUser` too.

Comment: That edit (complete rewrite. Also including the code? - it seems to have removed code (without any justification or explanation). And the stack trace.) was likely generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) and is completely unacceptable.